# Where can I find the source of "I perish today not because of the crime I committed, but because of the pardon I did not accept"?

Tags: reference-request, united-states, sermon

From a sermon illustration: That quote was the last words of a young man in southern USA (18th century), who was sentenced to be hung for a crime, whose family had interceded with the governor. The governor took a pardon enclosed in a Bible to the young man. But the young man refused anything religious, the Bible, and his unknown visitor.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Perhaps similar to this Supreme Court case a couple of hundred years ago (United States v. Wilson): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Wilson; also see:  https://www.columbianprogress.com/opinion-columns/historys-lone-refusal-presidential-pardon